# Not able to start activity using appium

Tags: java, appium, appium-android

I am trying to launch a transparent activity using appium android driver and also passing some optional intent arguments. It is always failing with 500 status and the command times out no matter how much I set abdExecTimeout capability value.

Sample code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "/path/to/app.apk");
capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.myapp.home.splash.SplashActivity");
capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.myapp.app");
capabilities.setCapability("udid","e76dcaaqs");
capabilities.setCapability("avdLaunchTimeout", 300000);
capabilities.setCapability("useKeystore", false);
capabilities.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions",true);
capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
capabilities.setCapability("skipUnlock", true);
capabilities.setCapability("androidInstallTimeout", 180000);
capabilities.setCapability("adbExecTimeout", 60000);
capabilities.setCapability("ignoreHiddenApiPolicyError", true);
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Oppo Reno");
capabilities.setCapability("appWaitForLaunch", false);
AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
Activity activity = new Activity("com.myapp.app", "com.myapp.instrumentation.persistence.preferences.PreferencesOverrideActivity");
String intentParam = "--es \"overrideData\" '[{\"pref_name\": \"MyPref\",\"overrides\": " +
        "[{\"key\": \"mykey\",\"value\": \"" + obj.getValue() + "\",\"type\": \"string\"}],\"clear\": false}]'";
activity.setOptionalIntentArguments(intentParam);
//            activity.setStopApp(true);
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
driver.startActivity(activity);
driver.launchApp();

} catch (OperationFailedException | MalformedURLException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output log

> [W3C (146a80b7)] Calling AppiumDriver.startActivity() with args:
> ["com.myapp.app","com.myapp.instrumentation.persistence.preferences.PreferencesOverrideActivity","com.myapp.app","com.myapp.home.splash.SplashActivity","","","","--es
> "overrideData" '[{"pref_name": "MyPreferences","overrides":
> [{"key": "myKey","value": "myValue"","type":
> "string"}],"clear": false}]' [AndroidDriver] Starting package
> 'com.myapp.app' and activity
> 'com.myapp.instrumentation.persistence.preferences.PreferencesOverrideActivity'
> [ADB] Running '/Users/user1/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -P
> 5037 -s e15adapa shell am start -W -n
> com.myapp.app/com.myapp.instrumentation.persistence.preferences.PreferencesOverrideActivity
> -S --es '"overrideData"' "'[{"pref_name": "MyPreferences","overrides": [{"key": "myKey","value":
> "myValue","type": "string"}],"clear": false}]'"'
> [Instrumentation] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=Process crashed.
> [Instrumentation] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0 [Instrumentation] The
> process has exited with code 0

The strange thing is the preference data is updated even if the process crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the reason. Appium by defaults adds `-W` to the adb command when startActivity is called which waits till the activity is launched. In my case it is a transparent activity and does not launch. So eventually the appium command times out and fails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "appWaitForLaunch to false".

Look [here](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup/#command-timed-out-after-x-ms) - From Appium Docs:

> There might be also situations where an activity does not return the
> control to the calling process at all, so am start call blocks forever
> independently of the value of appWaitDuration, thus causing the
> timeout. In such case setting appWaitForLaunch to false might help to
> resolve the issue. Although, by choosing this option, the driver
> cannot make sure the activity has fully started, so then it is up to
> the client code to verify the initial UI state is the one that is
> expected.